# php recordset in Laravel @foreach alternative

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Can you tell me how to do this properly please?

I'm using Laravel 8.  Passing a recordset to a page which I deal with using a foreach loop later in the page.  How do I get data out of it without a forloop?  I've bodged it using

```
@foreach ($sites as $site)
     <img src="{{$site->url}}" alt="Pic" id="bg-img" onclick = fill() />
@break
@endforeach
```

I've used a foreach loop as it works later in the page.

Yes it works but I'd like to know the proper way.

I've also tried:

```
{{$site->url}}
{{$sites->url}}
$sites['url']
```

I'm new to Laravel and rubbish with array type things in php.

Thank you

Am I allowed to ask this improvement type question?

Comment: If that is a set of multiple records, why do you want to remove the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just explained some of the statements you made.

For example, you have data like this:

```
----------------------------
| id | url                 |
----------------------------
| 1  | http://domain-1.tld |
| 2  | http://domain-2.tld |
| 3  | http://domain-3.tld |
| 4  | http://domain-4.tld |
| 5  | http://domain-5.tld |
----------------------------
```

For example, you have query :

```
$sites = Site::get();
```

The `get` method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance containing the results of the query where each result is an instance of the PHP `stdClass` object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

```
@foreach ($sites as $site)
    {{ $site->url }}
@endforeach
```

- If you use `$sites->url`, it will be an error, because there is no object :

  ```
  Property [url] does not exist on this collection instance.
  ```
- If you use `$sites['url']`, it will also be an error.
- You can use `$site['url']`, when you convert collection to array :

  ```
  $sites = Site::get()->toArray();
  ```

---

##### `@break`

When you use `break`, it will ends execution of the current `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do-while` or `switch` structure.

From your code, it will take the first iteration only.

```
@foreach ($sites as $site)
    @break // stop
@endforeach
```

---

> How do I get data out of it without a forloop?

Looks like you want to retrieve single row. You can use `first()` :

```
$site = Site::first();
```

```
$site->url;
```

Answer (score -3):

if you want to print all values of array.then there is no way without loop's. if you want to print in single value.it is only possible with in index/key only.

eg.
//this print all values
$array = ['car','bike','truck'];

foreach($array as $value)
echo $value;
endforeach

//this print single value
echo $value[0];

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that a HTML `<br>` does the same as PHP's `break`?

Comment: No <br> tag and php break is different. php break, brake the loop condition and <br> tag break the line.And next result show in next line.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. If these two approaches work completely different, why did you recommend both?

Comment: foreach ($sites as $site)
     <img src="{{$site->url}}" alt="Pic" id="bg-img" onclick = fill() />
break
endforeach this will show only one image if this $sites  is single dimentional  array

Comment: <br> tag is show all images in different-different line. thats the different.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it